# Suddenly I have to do a Captcha check

Tags: discussion

Over 14k points on here and now I get asked to do a captcha before posting wtf?

What has changed?

Comment: ...did you pass the captcha?  >squinty-suspicious-look<

Comment: I haven't heard of any site changes. Of course, that doesn't mean that no changes were made.

Answer (score 0):

It is unlikely that anything has/had changed. However, if you are on a mobile device, that *might* go some way to explaining it.

To quote (parts of) [this useful answer](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8061/72586) to [Captcha it is often only for my account?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8028/72586):

> The appearance of the CAPTCHA should be based on the [The Complete Rate-Limiting Guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164899/168244). I can see that the following scenarios might trigger it:
>
> ...
>
> - You want to be the first one posting an answer, so you want to post at least the code as soon as possible. Once you have something working, you post it, but fall prey to the "within 5 seconds of starting new post" CAPTCHA trigger.
> - Switching networks while being mobile and using the site to post content could trigger the CAPTCHA accidentally.
>
> ...
>
> - Being mobile [may send multiple requests to SE that are similar](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7510513#7510513), triggering the CAPTCHA.
>
> ...

Please check the linked answer, for more details.

Personally, I haven't been subjected to a Captcha for *years*, but I always access Stack Exchange from a static landline - so maybe that is why..?